# 6 Player X-Men Arcade Cabinet Compatibility

Tags: arcade, x-men

I've got a 6-player X-Men Arcade cabinet and I was wondering what other boards might be compatible with it. Can I use any Jamma compatible board? Will the dual monitors just mirror?

Comment: [Related meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12173/how-does-my-question-about-my-arcade-machine-not-fit-in-arqade)

Comment: If you have any questions about this machine that aren't on-topic here, you could try asking on [retrocomputing.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question was posted and answered here.](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/6-player-x-men-arcade-cabinet-compatibility)

Below is the answer that was answered and accepted.

> The board seems to be using standard Jamma connector for Player 1 and
>   Player 2 except for the -5V and the test switch. Player 3-6 controls
>   are using non-standart sub-harnesses.
>
> Practically any 6 player game which doesn't require -5V should work.
>   But you may need to modify those sub-harnesses. I didn't see the
>   details of the arcade monitor in the link you provided. You should
>   check refresh rate of the monitor, too.